# Compare date with a reference date and retain the closest

Tags: r, date

I have one table with two columns (Student Id and Enrollment Date)

```
      ID             EnrollDate
      1332           12/21/2005
      2322           10/30/1995
      1343           05/29/1990
```

I have another table with three columns (Student Id, Date1, and State)

```
      ID             Date1         State
      1332           12/16/2005    MO
      1332           12/12/2005    AL
      2322           10/30/1995    AK
      1343           02/01/1990    LO
      1343           03/15/1990    LO
      1343           03/05/1990    GA
```

I am tryin to create a third table based on this logic.

1. Check if there are observations with duplicate Id in table 2
2. If observations with duplicate Id is found then check their Date1 values with 
        EnrollDate for that Id. 
        For example: Observation 1 and 2 in table 2 are duplicate because same id (1332) , 
        now inorder to decide which obeservation to eliminate, check the Date1 for this Id 
        (12/16/2005 & 12/12/2005) with EnrollDate for the same Id(1332) in table 1 
        (12/16/2005) .
3. For this pair of duplicate, retain only observation from table2 where the Date1 
        is closest to EnrollDate
        i.e retain the 1st observation from Table2 because 12/16/2005 is closer to 
        12/21/2005.

   Similarly only the fifth observation is retained from table2, the fourth and sixth are 
         dropped because for this pair of observation with duplicate id (1343),
         03/15/1990 is closer to 05/29/1990.

The output should look like this.

```
       ID             Date1         State
      1332           12/16/2005    MO
      2322           10/30/1995    AK
      1343           03/15/1990    LO
```

Need help with this logic.

Comment: More than two duplicates with a value of ID possible? Please construct an example with as many edge cases as you can imagine. What to do with ties?

Comment: @BondedDust, yup possible, in this case there are no ties between Id and Date1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by='ID') %>% 
             group_by(ID) %>% 
             mutate(diff=  abs(as.Date(Date1, '%m/%d/%Y')- 
                             as.Date(EnrollDate, '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>% 
             filter(diff==min(diff)) %>% 
             select(-EnrollDate, -diff)
#    ID      Date1 State
#1 1332 12/16/2005    MO
#2 2322 10/30/1995    AK
#3 1343 03/15/1990    LO
```

Comment: for some reason %>% didnt work, I changed that to %.% and it worked perfect, :)

Comment: @KingFrazier I think you are using an older version of `dplyr`.  I use `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`